# Why is index necessary in this function?

Tags: python, indexing

I've made a code to ask for dog ages, but I'm trying to figure out why the index is necessary. Or, could you please explain how the index effects the code.Thank you!

```
def printYoungestDog(DogNames, DogAges):
  index = 0
  minAge = DogAges[0]
  minIndex = 0
  while index < len(DogAges):
    if DogAges[index] < minAge:
      minAge = DogAges[index]
      minIndex = index
    index = index +1
  print('')
  print ("Youngest dog is " + str(DogNames[minIndex])+ " at the still developing age of " + 
  str(minAge))
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the alternative in your opinion? How would you implement it?

Comment: The index is there so you can check all the values in `DogAges`. Generally, you would use a different approach in idiomatic python, you wouldn't use a while-loop for this, but it's a valid solution

Comment: `index` is used to iterate all the items in `DogAges`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how index is used to iterate! I think my main question is probably what exactly each line of code after "while" does, because I'm very confused (we had a format to work with). The minIndex and DogAges [Index] < minAge make very little sense to me

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `DogNames` and `DogAges` are two different lists with the name and the age of a dog in each list respectively.

The function iterates over all the values of the `DogAges` list and finds the age of the youngest dog and its index in the list. The `index` variable is used as the index and increases each time the loop is run. The loop finishes when `index` is one less than the length of the list, meaning that it has iterated over all positions in the list. Once the loop is finished, it has found the index of the youngest age in the `DogAges` list. It then uses this index to select the corresponding position in the `DogNames` list, essentially the name of the dog with the youngest age. It then prints the name of this dog and its age.